# Exponential integration rule

Tags: integration

Given the function $e^ae^{-ba}$

The indefinite integral is $\int e^ae^{-ba} \mathrm da = \int e^{a-ba} \mathrm da$ is $\frac{e^ae^{-ba}}{1-b}$

I get that $\int e^u = e^u\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm da}$.

I cannot seem to understand how the $(1-b)$ term ends up in the denominator.

Can someone point out the rule that I am missing that puts the $(1-b)$ in the denominator?

Comment: Briefly, it comes from $e^a e^{-ba} = e^{a-ba} = e^{(1-b)a}$.

Comment: Differentiate $e^{a-ba}$. How does it compare to your integrand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a-ba=(1-b)a$. So
$$\int e^ae^{-ba}\,da = \int e^{a-ba}\,da = \int e^{(1-b)a}\,da.$$
Setting $u=(1-b)a$, we have $du = (1-b)da$, or $\frac{1}{1-b}\,du = da$. Hence
$$\int e^{a}e^{-ba}\,da = \int e^{(1-b)a}\,da = \int \frac{1}{1-b}e^u\,du = \frac{1}{1-b}e^u+C = \frac{e^{(1-b)a}}{1-b}+C.$$

I don't understand what you mean by "$\int e^u = e^u\frac{du}{da}$" (there seem to be lots of things missing, like a $d\Box$ in the integral and a constant of integration).

Comment: There are probably things missing which is probably aiding in my confusion. What I was missing is that $du=(1-b)da; \frac{1}{1-b}du=da$ Thank you.